# Python 3 installation on windows running from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just curious, is there a particular reason why Python 3.x is not installed on Windows to run default with the command line "python3", like it does on Mac OSX and Linux? Is there some kind of way to configure Python so that it runs like this? Thanks.

EDIT: Just to add, the reason I am asking is because I have both the Python 2 and 3 interpreter installed on my computer, and so it is ambiguous, as both are run using the command "python".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> the reason I am asking is because I have both the Python 2 and 3 interpreter installed on my computer, and so it is ambiguous, as both are run using the command "python".

To run Python 2 executable:

```
C:\> py -2
```

To run Python 3  executable:

```
C:\> py -3
```

where `py` is a [Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) that is bundled with your Python 3 installation.

`py` recognizes the shebang (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python3` causes Python 3 executable to be run), it respects virtualenv (if you run `py` without specifying the explicit python executable version) i.e., run:

```
C:\> py your_script.py
```

and the correct python version is used automatically -- you don't need to specify the Python version on the command-line explicitly.

> is there a particular reason why Python 3.x is not installed on Windows to run default with the command line "python3", like it does on Mac OSX and Linux?

OSX and Linux have `python` executable installed by default as a rule and it refers to Python 2 version in most cases at the moment that is why you need a separate `python3` name there.

There is no Python on Windows by default. And therefore any version that you've installed is just `python` (I guess). The recommended way to manage multiple python versions is to use the Python launcher.

> Is there some kind of way to configure Python so that it runs like this?

If you want to type `python3 some_script.py`  instead of `py some_script.py` or even just `some_script` (assuming `.py` is in `%PATHEXT%` and Python launcher is configured to run Python scripts (check `assoc .py` and `ftype Python.File`) -- the default) then create a bat-file e.g., `python3.cmd` and put it in `%PATH%`:

```
"C:\path to\Python 3.X\python.exe" %*
```

Answer (score 2):

You likely missed the checkbox at the bottom of the installer.

Full documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Then, I think you just run `python`, not `python3` from the Command Prompt. The reason Unix systems have `python3` is because `python` defaults to Python2.x in many systems.

[image: Install window]

Comment: I very much clicked the box. However, to run from the command line, you type "python" instead of "python3".

Comment: That's a problem because I have both python2 and 3 installed, so it is ambiguous (you use "python" to run both)

Comment: Windows looks at the path and takes whichever "python" comes first.

Comment: I'm well aware of the PATH workings. You should've specified you had python2 already. I think you are able to rename the python.exe from Py3 to python3.exe

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the python bin folder to your path. You can do it manually but when you install python i remember you have an option to do that.

Comment: I very much clicked the box to add it to path. However, to run from the command line, you type "python" instead of "python3".

Comment: who upvotes it? Look at your Python installation: there is no bin folder on Windows. There are `python.exe`, `pythonw.exe` files in the root of Python installation. There is no `python3.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I work with multiple Python 2.x and 3.x distros on Windows.  Some of them are "portable" - i.e. not recorded in the Windows registry, and therefore not accessible by the version-selector `py.exe` delivered with Python 3.3+.  To save my sanity, I wrote `SelectPython.bat` which is [available on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jezhill/selectpython).  It configures the `PYTHONHOME`, `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` variables according to the target you give it (a relative or absolute path to the parent directory of `python.exe`).  You can do so in a way that is sticky for the rest of your command-line session:

```
> SelectPython C:\Path\To\Desired\Version\Of\Python
> python
```

or transiently, i.e. to call a particular python command without otherwise affecting the environment of the shell you're calling it from:

```
> SelectPython C:\Path\To\Desired\Version\Of\Python  python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
```

You may find it helpful.