# Cmd Windows "python" command works, but "python3" doesn't although my python version is 3.6

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-10, anaconda

So I have followed a couple of posts here such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953124/python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).

So I have installed python 3.6 with Anaconda. Then I went into the PATH and I inserted the path to Python.

So now when I type into the cmd "python" I get the response

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However if I type in "python3" I get the usual problem

```
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why is that?

Comment: No need, you already are running python3, batteries included!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question may have already been answered; see [this answer to: Python 3 installation on windows running from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223417). Specifically:

> OSX and Linux have `python` executable installed by default as a rule
>   and it refers to Python 2 version in most cases at the moment that is
>   why you need a separate `python3` name there.
>
> There is no Python on Windows by default. And therefore any version
>   that you've installed is just `python` (I guess). The recommended way to
>   manage multiple python versions is to use the Python launcher.

TL;DR: `python3` is not a valid command on Windows, regardless of the distribution that it comes with (Anaconda in your case).

Comment: Thank you a lot! So if I wanted to create a virtual environment, should I just use `python -m venv venv` instead of `python3 -m venv venv`? To get this command, I am referring to this tutorial that I found online: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: @Euler_Salter Glad to be of help! You are correct, of course. On Windows, `python -m venv venv` will create a venv with the name _venv_ in your current directory, provided that you have Python 3.3 or later installed.

Answer (score 1):

Euler_Salter.

If you have installed Anaconda, I have a tip for you.

Before giving you a tip, there is background tip for you.

Python has a lot of modules and their dependency. 
So It provides virtual environment to isolate from dependency issues.

Anaconda also provides it.

So, You can easily find "Anaconda Prompt" in you windows system.

Here is the Short Cut
Win Key -> Type "Anaconda Prompt" on Search Input

Or

You can execute it using command.

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" %UserProfile%\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat 
%UserProfile%\Anaconda3
```

And I think that you're confused of the difference between linux and windows.

As I know, If you install python3 on Ubuntu, there is python3 binary path, or symlink for it. That is, whether or not there is python3 is not important thing.

You can just make a symlink for it.

See it. https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

I sincerely hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I am using Windows, but know little or nothing about Linux to be honest. So should I make a virtual environment with anaconda then?