# Why does my program run locally, but not in the virtual environment?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm using PyCharm. When I press the run button, my file runs fine:

[image]

But when I try to run the same file in my virtualenv, nothing happens:

[image]

My interpreter settings *are* set to the virtualenv, so what else could be wrong?

Comment: my guess is that python3 isn't the same python installed in your virtualenv; and thusly can't find the necessary modules to run the python script 'run.py'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac users:

> The answer was that python3 wasn't using the same site-packages as the
> virtualenv; and thusly, running `python3 run.py` would not run.
>
> Ensure that you're running the virtualenv's python binary instead of
> the generally installed python3 binary.

Windows users:

> There is no Python on Windows by default. And therefore any version that you've installed is just python (I guess). The recommended way to manage multiple python versions is to use the Python launcher. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356397/7078496)